# My app does not work when set to 'default startup app' on Microsoft Windows IOT

Tags: win-universal-app, windowsiot, dragonboard

I am using Windows IOT on a DragonBoard 410C. I have created a windows universal app that makes use of a microphone. Running the application remotely through Visual Studio 2015 and it runs perfectly.

However, when I set it up as a default startup app following these guidelines ->
https://www.hackster.io/AnuragVasanwala/windows-10-iot-core-setting-startup-app-887ed0, it behaves strangely. Sometimes it works perfect and sometimes it doesn't work at all. I have tried pushing the app from the windows IOT web server as well as PowerShell, but both have the same outcome.

I have tried everything. I even did the entire process using a minnowboard and a raspberry pi 2 and got the same problem, so I do not think it is a hardware problem. The app has been written in C#. I seriously doubt that it could be a code issue that is causing this problem, but I may be wrong.

Edit (22/2/2016): I also tried setting the windows Sample app as a default startup app (https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SpeechRecognitionAndSynthesis), however, this app too doesn't perform properly on startup and hangs, eventually crashing. I am now pretty sure that it may be a windows side issue. Is there any other set up that may be required for it to work properly?

Comment: Are you logging any error messages? You will need to log error message to find the needle in the haystack.

Comment: I will try to manage the logs, but I do not think that, that will solve anything.The problem I am facing is this -> The speech synthesis library does not properly read out sentences. It keeps breaking mid sentence as though it is stuttering and skips out many words. Running this on a pc works fine. Just on the dragonboard it gets messed up.